# Timer in Console based program

Tags: timer

So right now, I have a school project. It's a basic math question program. User inputs their answer and the for loop checks if correct. But to add another layer to it i want to add a time limit to each question. When the question appears, they have exactly 6 seconds to answer.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {

        System.out.println(questions[i]);
        temp = in.nextInt();

        if(temp == answers[i])
        {
            score++;
        }

    }
```

This isn't all the program's code, this loop is using an array to ask a question and check the users answer to see if its correct.I want to add a timer for 6 seconds, that will be used to only allow 6 seconds to answer and if they dont the score doesnt increase.

Comment: what are you asking exactly

Comment: Use multiple thread